# Blank page when deploying React App to gh pages

Tags: reactjs, github, web-deployment, github-pages, mern

I am trying to deploy my react app onto to gh pages but it just shows up as a blank screen. I have tried everything, and nothing seems to work. I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NapRkCazks and everything seems to run fine except there is a blank page when I type in the url. Here is my repo: https://github.com/nupurd89/onlineshopping.git

I am super lost and nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Follow the steps from https://pages.github.com

Comment: I dont see a package.json in your repo. Thats strange.

Comment: There are two package.json files, one in the main repo and one in the "ecommerce-front-end" file

Comment: Did you sort out this issue? I can see you have a live gh-page for it, i'm experiencing the same issue and wondering if you could share how you fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem in my case that I am deploying a static create react app [App-filter-review] system and my screen show blank screen too.

#Fix No 1

1. The first issue is the incorrect url config, for the homepage,as it is given everywhere to correct it

#Fix No 2

2. If you are using React-router>v4.0 in the React app the include Basename acc to defined property
   [Basename add this basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} in Browser Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UDe3.png)

   This Article really helps out if you are using another stack too.
   https://maximorlov.com/deploying-to-github-pages-dont-forget-to-fix-your-links/

#Fix No 3

3. If you are deploying the system on Heroku or GH-pages try to correct Case sensitive issues while directing to JS/CSS file while configuring as these systems are using Linux container that is case sensitive

Link to My Github Page that is fixed by Fix no2 is here
https://amancode27.github.io/App-Review-Filter/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed the right version of gh-pages (npm install gh-pages --save-dev).

Also, add the following properties to package.json file.

```
"homepage": "http://{your_username}.github.io/{your_repo-name}"
"scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

Run the following command :

```
npm run deploy.
```

Your GitHub repository > Settings > Pages

- Under the Source tab, select the "gh-pages" branch.

Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: I did all that but it still doesnt work. I added everything into the package.json file in "ecommerce-front-end" folder. Im very confused on why it still doesnt work.

Comment: https://github.com/nupurd89/onlineshopping/blob/master/ecommerce-front-end/package.json here is the link to the json

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue while using a custom domain I bought on namecheap, even after following the recommended set up (adding the A records/CNAME on namecheap, adding the deploy scripts in package.json, custom name on github, etc.)

The solution I found here https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/issues/53 worked for me.

I had to remove my repo name from the end of my package.json homepage property, so it looks like this now:

"homepage": "https://gitname.github.io"

After redeploying and then refreshing my browser page / cache, and I'm not getting a blank page anymore. I was using create-react-app, namecheap for the custom domain, and gh pages for hosting.